# Refactoring - auto extract method to function

Tags: delphi, refactoring, keyboard-shortcuts

I have code like below:

```
procedure T.Foo;
var
    bar: Integer;
    bar2: String;
begin
    bar :=  Abs((Round(1.2) + 17) * -1);
    bar2 := IntToStr(bar);
end;
```

I want to extract a function using "Extract Method"(Ctrl+Shift+M) for the code to look like:

```
function T.ExtractedMethod: Integer;
begin
    result := Abs((Round(1.2) + 17) * -1);
end;

procedure T.Foo;
var
    bar: Integer;
    bar2: String;
begin
    bar :=  ExtractedMethod;
    bar2 := IntToStr(bar);
end;
```

unfortunately when I am selecting line:

```
bar :=  Abs((Round(1.2) + 17) * -1); //Ctrl+Shift+M on this line
```

it proposes a procedure with var parameter:

```
procedure T.ExtractedMethod(var bar: Integer);
begin
  bar := Abs((Round(1.2) + 17) * -1);
end;
```

Is there a chance to force the use function?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. *Extract method* only produces procedures with var params. Been something I've wanted changed for years now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Extract Method refactoring in Delphi always creates procedures.